# How to use GCC from gcc_9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb without installing the package?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I need to build a library from C sources for Arm `aarch64` architecture and Linux Ubuntu `x86 64` using **GCC** toolchain - my host work machine is Ubuntu 20.04 too.

For Arm there are GCC toolchains available for download at [developer.arm-com](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/downloads).

What I do for Arm is:

- download the zipped toolchain
- unzip it to a `/temp` directory
- build the library telling the underlying build system to use GCC from `/temp/gcc`

I would like to do the same for Linux x86 64, so, instead of Arm, target Linux Ubuntu x86 64. **I don't want to use the GCC natively installed on the system.**

Where do I find the GCC toolchain targeting Ubuntu `x86 64` architecture?

I have found the https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/gcc/download page. There I got the `gcc_9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb` package. Can I "temporarily unzip" the deb, in order to use GCC without installing it on the system? Is there a zip instead of only deb?

Comment: Download the source for whatever version of GCC you want to use, build it, and install it into your own home directory. See [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html) for details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That seems like overly complicated. I would expect there are prepared packages already.

Comment: [Installing packages into local directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193695/installing-packages-into-local-directory) And no it's not always possible and often a bad idea. On the plus-side the building of GCC is easily scriptable, and doesn't have to be done more than once or (worst case scenario) twice a year if you want the latest. If you must stick with an older version, then it's a one-time thing.

Comment: Alright, very useful insight, thanks. Maybe add it as answer?

Comment: If you want to use an automated system, you could use [crosstool-ng](https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng). They have sample configuration for *x86-64-unknown-linux-gnu*.